# Fasboot Devices not getting attached XIAOMI MI A3

Tags: xiaomi, mi

I have the *Xiaomi Mi A3* and I'm currently on both phone and PC latest stock update. I am using Windows 10 20H2 and I have tried everything – but still don't get it.

I tried another Mi A3 and it got attached normally. I've tried installing all kind of drivers and different ports, nothing. When suddenly it worked and I installed the stock ROM – but because the stock ROM is kinda laggy and ugly I want to change it. But I can't because I am also on stock recovery and I can't install another recovery because my device isn't recognized in fastboot mode.

My device is recognized in adb mode and in edl mode as well, only not in fastboot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116829/discussion-on-question-by---fasboot-devices-not-getting-attached-xiao).

Comment: you are right. it **can** be ROM related. but i doubt that is the case here, as you stated you have two similar devices with same ROM, but claim only one device is not detected https://www.getdroidtips.com/what-is-fastbootd-how-to-enable-and-boot