# fasboot devices not getting attached xiaomi mi a3 no sound of attaching no nothing

Tags: adb, fastboot, xiaomi, mi

I have the Xiaomi Mi A3 and I'm currently on both phone and PC latest stock update. I am using Windows 10 20H2 and I have tried everything – but still don't get it.

I tried another Mi A3 and it got attached normally. I've tried installing all kind of drivers and different ports, nothing. When suddenly it worked and I installed the stock ROM – but because the stock ROM is kinda laggy and ugly I want to change it. But I can't because I am also on stock recovery and I can't install another recovery because my device isn't recognized in fastboot mode.

My device is recognized in adb mode and in edl mode as well, only not in fastboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fasboot Devices not getting attached XIAOMI MI A3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231442/fasboot-devices-not-getting-attached-xiaomi-mi-a3)